# BigQuery invalid table name error when using Standard SQL in BigQuery API's

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client, airflow

I am trying query the table and store the result in another BigQuery table using python BigQuery API. But when I use standard SQL in query part it throws invalid table name error. How to use standard SQL in BigQuery API? I am using airflow BigQuery hoooks

```
'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'destinationTable': {
                'tableId': u 'our_table_name',
                'datasetId': 'our_dataset_id',
                'projectId': 'our_project_id'
            },
            'useLegacySql': False,
            'allowLargeResults': True,
            'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            'query': u'SELECT * FROM `projectID.datasetId.tablename`',
            
        }
    }
```

```
Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Invalid table name: `projectId:datasetId.tableId`', u'location': u'`projectId:datasetId.tableId`'}.
```

Comment: can you share job id to look at specific details

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky job id: job_lIaunDu3LHrgwm_KDOoxwmH39xw

Comment: I also need project name please

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky did you get project Id?

Comment: Thanks, I got it - answer posted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is confusing, but the root cause is that this query was interpreted as Legacy SQL, not as Standard SQL. In JSON (unlike, say, in Python), boolean literals `true` and `false` must be lowercase, per [JSON standard Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-3):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
> ```
>   false null true
> ```
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are
> allowed.

So if you change

```
        `'useLegacySql': False,`
```

to

```
        `'useLegacySql': false,`
```

it should work

Comment: yes, it works. I changed into 'useLegacySql': 'false'. Thank you so much

Comment: @MJK you should mark this as an _answered_ question if it worked.